# How to not show the "has been created" message?

Tags: hooks, 9

I want to remove the message that is output in the message area when a new node is created.  A typical message may look like this.

"Article My article has been created."

I examine the node in `hook_node_insert`, and when certain criteria is met, I want to delete the message or prevent the message from appearing.

I've tried to put the following in `hook_node_insert`:

```
 $messages = \Drupal::messenger()->all();
 dpm($messages, 'messages');
```

It outputs an empty array: `messages => []`.

This similar question for Drupal 7 [How do I change/modify an update content message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/10641/12076) suggests `hook_message_alter()`. I haven't found that, or a replacement, for Drupal 9.

It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [How do I programmatically change a system message?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/212635/12076)

I don't think it is a duplicate, but that question contains a single answer that is helpful to my use case.  *Most* of the answers are not a good fit for this question, so I believe that my question presents a more focused problem and deserves to stay open.

I went through all the answers. These are my findings as to how well they fit *this* question:

- The accepted one (use `\Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();`) does not work when placed in `hook_node_insert`, and no alternative placement is suggested.
- The most upvoted one (implement `hook_preprocess_status_messages`) does not fire *after* node creation form has been submitted and has no effect.
- To use hack the `$SESSION` variable (`unset($SESSION['_symfony_flashes']['status'][0]);`) does not work in `hook_node_insert`and no other placement is suggested.

The answer from Achraf JEDAY, with 1 upvote prior to mine today (Adding a a custom submit handler to the node creation form) works. Cudos.

This is also the accepted answer (from Patrick Kenny) here.

Comment: @FreeRadical, I don't know what you mean by red herrings. The topic over there is more general and several years old. It evolved by introducing the then new messenger service and you have to read the entire thread if you want to come to the conclusion you summarized here in the question.

Comment: I don't know the expression red herring, but it reads like you are not acknowledging the effort of each one participating to advance the topic, which is more general than this one. BTW the first vote to the latest answer was from me when I referenced it in my comment. Late answers often have few votes simply because they are too late to get much attention. But this can change over time when people like us are voting.

Comment: A "red herring" is an English idiom meaning something that distracts from what is relevant to answering a specific question. It was not my intent to disparage the answers in the linked question - only to say that most answers was not relevant to *this* one. I removed the phrase since you object to it.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, one of the answers there worked. But there was plenty that did not help in my specific use case, including the accepted and most upvoted answers. I've added text to the question where I comment on how well these answers fit my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a custom message in a hook, you can clear the messages and then add your custom message.  This is quick and easy, and it can be done in most hooks.

Unfortunately, this won't work with `hook_node_insert()`, so an alternative is to add a custom submit handler to the node creation form and call the Messenger service statically:

```
  \Drupal::messenger()->deleteByType('status');
  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('My new custom message.'));
```

This will get very messy if you override a lot of messages, but if you just need to change a few, this is the approach I use.

Comment: It seems the \Drupal::messenger API does not provide a way to delete a single message.  A clumsy workaround that worked for me was to grab all message of a particular type (`$messages = \Drupal::messenger()->all()['status']`), then delete all messages of that type, then add back the ones I didn't want to delete into the messenger using `addMessage()`.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted and upvoted Patrick Kenny's answer, since it provides 99% of the solution.

However, I realized that I also needed this worked out:

> I examine the node in `hook_node_insert`, and when certain criteria is met, I want to delete the message or prevent the message from appearing.

This was added to the question *after* Patrick Kenny answered, but for those interested in how this final step was solved:

1. If certain criteria is met insert an error message `\Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('Error'));`
2. Sniff for the error message in the submit handler, and if it is present, delete the unwanted status message.

Voilà!